# Return value of 0 from MySQL query if empty

Tags: mysql

I use this query to get a value for a range of months. For example, January 1.10, February 2.37.

```
"SELECT SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE)
FROM royalties
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '".$datemin."' AND '".$datemax."'
GROUP BY DATE 
ORDER BY DATE ASC"
```

Is there a way to return a value of 0 if there are no rows within a certain month?

Comment: Is it possible there is no data at all for a month?

Comment: Yes, there are some months that will not have a single row in the table, so no data for that month

Comment: Do you query one month at a time?

Comment: No, just the one query returns all of my values